# show tags of custom post type ONLY

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, tags, terms

I have a custom post type with tags included as a taxonomy, I am trying to display a list of all the tags that are in the custom post type only. I initially used:

```
wp_tag_cloud();
```

which generates the list of tags with links fine but it shows the tags of the normal posts with it. I tried to query the posts like this:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'archive' ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
        wp_reset_query();
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

but it shows the tags in duplicate loads. e.g if I had the tag as `test`, it would say `test`,`test`,`test` and so on.

This is the code that declares the tags

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

Does anybody know a way of displaying a list of tags that are specific to my custom post type only?

Answer (score 6):

The above solutions work correctly but aren't exactly optimized. Here's a method that queries that database ONCE for the data you're looking for, and gives you a list of term objects. It can accept a post_type argument, and if one is not supplied, will use the post_type of the current global $post object.

```
function post_type_tags( $post_type = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $post_type ) ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type();
    }

    return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT tr.object_id ) 
            AS count, tt.taxonomy, tt.description, tt.term_taxonomy_id, t.name, t.slug, t.term_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} p 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr 
            ON p.ID=tr.object_id 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt 
            ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t 
            ON t.term_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        WHERE p.post_type=%s 
            AND tt.taxonomy='post_tag' 
        GROUP BY tt.term_taxonomy_id 
        ORDER BY count DESC
    ", $post_type ) );
}
```

So if you called `post_type_tags( 'archive' )`, for instance, you'd get a list of term objects for post_tag in descending order of popularity for 'archive' post types.

You can then emit your list of links like so:

```
$archive_tags = post_type_tags( 'archive' );

foreach( $archive_tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ). '">' . esc_html( $tag->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Just perfect! Please accept this answer

Answer (score -1):

```
 
     query_posts( 'post_type'=> 'custom_post_type_name' );
     if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     $custom_post_tags = get_the_tags();
     if ( $custom_post_tags  ) {
        foreach( $custom_post_tags as $tag ) {
           $tags_arr[] = $tag -> name; 
        }
     }
     endwhile; endif;
     if( $tags_arr ) {
         $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr );
         foreach( $uniq_tags_arr as $tag ) {
             // LIST ALL THE TAGS FOR DESIRED POST TYPE
             $tag_link = get_term_by('name', $tag, 'post_tag');
             echo 'term_id). '" title="'.$tag.'">' .$tag. '';
         }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you so much! The only thing is it dosen't contain a link to the tag, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yeah you just need to add this in the above foreach loop echo "<li><a href='".$sanitizeTag ."' title="'.$tag.'">$tag</a></li>";

Comment: hey I just tweaked my code little while use the above code and vote me up if you really satisfied with my solution.

Comment: Thanks but its showing the same tag twice when i use that code still!

Comment: $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr ); will remove the duplicate value just try no there is something went wrong I guess. Are they really same or seems like some white space or dot with it. please check it in your tags. Because its my working code.

Comment: It is really strange, I will have another play around, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
query_posts( 'post_type'=> 'custom_post_type_name' );
     if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     $custom_post_tags = get_the_tags();
     if ( $custom_post_tags  ) {
        foreach( $custom_post_tags as $tag ) {
           $tags_arr[] = $tag -> name; 
        }
     }
     endwhile; endif;
     if( $tags_arr ) {
         $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr );
         foreach($tags_arr as $tag ) {
             // LIST ALL THE TAGS FOR DESIRED POST TYPE
             $sanitizeTag =  sanitize_title($tag);

$current_tag = get_term_by('name', $tag, 'post_tag');

             echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($current_tag->term_id). '">' .$tag. '</a>';
         }
    }
```

This will give the list of tags with the links to the tag.

Comment: Awesome, It shows the link now but after testing properly it still shows duplicates, I have two posts with the same tag of 'test' and it shows test twice when i use that code

Comment: check the title/slug of the tag you are using. There must be something which is making both the tags not to be identical. Otherwise `array_unique` must have solved this issue.

Comment: I deleted all the tags and added new ones and tested again, im using only one tag its not duplicating it in the admin, just in when it shows

Comment: Is the code working now? or do you need to make any more changes?

Comment: Not working, still showing doubles!

Answer (score -1):

@user34466
This should work to solve the duplicate issue:

```
                <ul>
            <?php
                query_posts(array( 'post_type'=> 'work' ));
                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $custom_post_tags = get_the_tags();
                if ( $custom_post_tags ) {
                    foreach( $custom_post_tags as $tag ) {
                        $tags_arr[] = $tag -> name;
                    }
                }
                endwhile; endif;
                if( $tags_arr ) {
                    $uniq_tags_arr = array_unique( $tags_arr );
                 foreach( $uniq_tags_arr as $tag ) {
                     // LIST ALL THE TAGS FOR DESIRED POST TYPE
                     $sanitizeTag =  sanitize_title($tag);
                     $tag_link = get_term_by('name', $tag, 'post_tag');
                     echo '<li><a href="'. get_tag_link($tag_link->term_id).'">' .$tag. '</a></li>';
                     }
                 }
             ?>
            </ul>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Please explain _why_ that was actually helpful. Thanks.